# Spark query difference in performance on same kind of data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, so I was experimenting something like this

```
  val values1= sparkSession.range(1,1000000)
  val values2= sparkSession.range(1,1000000)
  val values3= sparkSession.range(0,100000,2)
  val values4= sparkSession.range(0,100000,2)

  private val frame1: DataFrame = values1.join(values3,"id")
  frame1.count()
  private val frame3: DataFrame = values2.join(values4,"id")
  frame3.count()
```

[image: Spark UI]

My question is why later task takes so less time though I am using different data (might be identical in content). ?

Comment: because most of data is loaded & available in memory & it will reuse that.

Comment: @Srinivas in that case why values2/values4 are loaded while values1/values3 are not?

Comment: What I am telling is frame1 is already loaded memory .. that's why frame3 took less time than frame1

Comment: If you want to check difference.. open two spark shell and try running one query in each and check time

Comment: For this kind of timing, that is probably noise in time measurement. Maybe your core was not available due to other kind of processes.
The results should be identical.

Comment: @Srinivas but for both calculations I am using different dataFrames right ?

for frame1 , I am using values1,values3 
for frame2 , I am using values2,values4
Therefore,different data for different operations. So how can it reuse ?